# angular2 - aspnet core: object properties undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm using angular 2 on the client side and aspnet core on server side. I'm trying to delete an item from the database but somehow I'm not able to do it because:

```
itemToDelete.projectId is undefined.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Myproject.services.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MyProjectsService {
private url: string = 'api/myprojects';

constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthService) { }

///->itemToDelete.projectID undefined///

deleteProject(itemToDelete: Project) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + itemToDelete.projectId, { headers: this.authService.authJsonHeaders() })
               .map((res: Response) => res.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

myProjects.component.ts

```
export class MyProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
    myProjectsList: Project[] = [];
    selectedItem: Project = null;
    project: Project = null;

constructor(private myProjectsService: MyProjectsService, private toastrService: ToastrService) { }

initProject(): Project {
    var newProject = new Project();
    return newProject;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getMyProjects();
    this.project = this.initProject();
}

selectCurrentItem(thisItem: Project, event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.selectedItem = thisItem;
    this.project = Object.assign({}, thisItem);
}

deleteProject(itemToDelete: Project, event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.myProjectsService.deleteProject(itemToDelete)
        .subscribe((data: ViewModelResponse) => {
            if (data != null && data.statusCode == 200) {
                this.showSuccess('Delete', data.value);
                this.getMyProjects();
            }
            else {
                this.showError('Delete', "An error occurred");
            }
        },
        (error: any) => {
            this.showError('Delete', JSON.stringify(error));
        });
}
```

project.ts

```
export class Project {

projectId : number;
userId: number;
projectName: string;
}
```

myProjectsComponent.chtml

```
 @using MoviePrepper.ViewModels
 @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
 @addTagHelper *,MoviePrepper
 @model Project

 <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let item of myProjectsList" (click)="selectCurrentItem(item,$event)" [class.info]="item==selectedItem">
          <td par="item" cdfor="ProjectID"></td>
          <td par="item" cdfor="ProjectName"></td>
              <td>
                   <button type="button" (click)="deleteProject(item, $event)">X</button>
                   <button type="button" (click)="changeMode('edit', item, $event)">?</button>
              </td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What is calling the MyProjectsComponent deleteProject method? Is it passing the object in correctly?

Comment: I've added the html

Answer (score 0):

Try to define like this,

When you say null, that is being assigned as null,

```
export class MyProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
    myProjectsList: Project[] = [];
    selectedItem: Project;
    project: Project;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but itemToDelete.projectId is still undefined. I can see the Project and it's properties with the correct values but somehow it doesn't reflect into the angular 2 model of project.projectId

Comment: I've adde the html

Comment: where are you assigning the projectlist?